# python program doesn't stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I was trying to solve euler project problem "3" and it partially succeeded but the program doesn't stop even after getting the desired answer and getting the correct answer.

the statement of the problem: 
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

here is my code :

```
 #function to check if number is prime

    def check_prime(num):
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num%i == 0:
              return False
        return True
    #desired number to find it prime factors

    desired_num = 600851475143
    #generator of all prime numbers until that number

    x=(ii for ii in range(2,desired_num) if check_prime(ii))

    #generator of prime factors

    y=(j for j in x if desired_num%j==0)

    #looping through generator y
    for k in y:
        print(k)
```

output result
 71
 839
 1471
 6857(the correct answer)
but as i mentioned program continue running

Comment: `(ii for ii in range(2,desired_num) if check_prime(ii))` you do realize this is a pretty massive loop that calls a function that loops, right?

Comment: There are [algorithms to find prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) which will leave you with a complete set of primes up to some maximum number, which will perform much better.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard thanks for your reply, i do realize that, and i don't know if it's actually the problem i am a beginner, i tried this out and my concern was if things would go fast and get my answer immediately when i run, and i get my answers fast, but still program doesn't end, and i can't figure out why specifically.

Comment: @ZacCrites thank you so much, it's very helpful.